# Windows Command to identify folders with only one file and move the file

Tags: batch-file, command-line-interface

I need a command to run from the Windows CLI to identify any folders (or sub folders) that contain only one file. If the folder contains two files, it should not be included. In the end, I want the single files to be moved to another folder and the original folder to be deleted.

I found this code, but I do not know how to proceed from here..

```
@echo off
for /d /r "d:\base\folder" %%a in (*) do (
    dir /b /a-d "%%a" 2>nul |find /c /v "" |findstr "^1$" >nul && >>file.txt echo %%a
)
```

I appreciate any help I can get.

Thanks.

Comment: You could try [this Super User question and answers](https://superuser.com/questions/597802/how-to-batch-delete-folders-with-only-one-file-in-it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Robocopy to filter the folders very well, which only contain one file. It is filtered only once - not several times. Move and delete as usual.

```
for /f "tokens=1*" %%C in ('
 robocopy /L /s "d:\base\folder" ".. ListFolders ..\\" /njh /nc /nfl /njs ^
 ^|findstr /irc:" 1..:" ^|sort /r ') do @echo move %%D* D:\Dest && echo rd %%D
```